# Updating parameters in group using PowerBIClient C#

Tags: c#, powerbi, powerbi-api

I'm trying to update a parameter of a powerbi dataset using the PowerBIClient class with C#.
I can perform other method calls with no problem.
I can get parameters.
Updating parameter results in Bad Request. If I call the update method with non existing param I get Not found.
I don't understand what is causing the bad request. Code bellow:

```
...
            await pbiClient.Datasets.UpdateParametersInGroupAsync(
               workspaceId,
               datasetId,
               new UpdateMashupParametersRequest(new UpdateMashupParameterDetails("Param1", "123")
              ));
...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the parameter cannot be of types Any or Binary.
Changing the parameter from type Any to Text solved it.